# beacon interval & number of APs benefits/downsides/

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11

As far as I understand, A beacon announces an AP's availability & capability, to allow clients to make decisions about which AP to connect to, does this mean it matters less the less APs are available, for example the higher the available numbers of APs for clients to connect to, the better it's to have a lower interval, & vice versa, so for example a network with multiple clients that only connect to one AP, would benefit from highest interval time without any downsides, no?

> provide a timing signal to synchronise communications with the devices using the network (the members of a service set)

also does this mean bacon interval & DTIM affect the actual synchronization of traffic between the clients & AP in anyway, the information I found online is contradicting, some people claim the client will hold to traffic waiting to hear the beacon before transmitting, which sounds none sense, more importantly do these two settings affect the latency of sent packet of data, in any way?

Comment: If you're serious about latency, use a wired connection (Ethernet).

Comment: @Zac67 I already do when possible, but some clients are wireless only & I'm curious about the latency for them, if it changes with changing those values or not & how

Comment: Wireless latency changes all the time, the beacon interval is just one tiny variable in that.